# Which of the following statements are valid propositions about subvergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let's say a series *subverges* if the sequence of partial sums contains a subsequence that converges. Consider this (invented) definition for a moment, and then decide which of the following statements are valid propositions about subvergent series:

(a) If $(a_n)$ is bounded, then $\sum a_n$ subverges.

I give $(a_n) = (-1)^n$ as a counterexample.  It is bounded and  $\sum (-1)^n$ converges to 0, but it has (as far as I can tell) no convergent subsequence of partial sums.

(b) All convergent series are subvergent

I say no to that as well, and again I offer $(a_n) = (-1)^n $ as a counter example.

(c) If $\sum |a_n|$ subverges, then $\sum a_n$ also subverges.

My intuition says yes, because if any subsequence of partial sums converges absolutely, then it has to converge conditionally, as well. Right?

(d) If $\sum a_n$ subverges, then $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

I can think of an example for which it is true: $\sum \dfrac{1} {n}$ subverges since it contains the subseries $\sum \dfrac {1} {n^2}$, $\sum \dfrac {1} {n^3}$, $\sum \dfrac {1} {2^n}$, etc, all of which converge.

As far as going through the mechanics of some kind of formal proof on parts (c) and (d) I'm stuck. Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Yes, this is a real  problem, Exercise 2.7.6 from "Understanding Analysis" by Springer.

Comment: a) That series does not converge, but does have a convergent subsequence of partial sums, so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: @AndréNicolas could you please elaborate?

Comment: a) Let $s_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$, then notice that $s_{2n} = 0$ is a convergent subsequence. So $\sum a_n$ subverges. c) A series of non-negative terms subverges if and only if it converges, thanks to the monotonicity. Thus (c) is really a statement about absolute convergence.

Comment: The simplest way to show that the series does not converge is to note that the terms do not go to $0$. But (if your sequence starts with $a_1$) all odd numbered partial sums are $1$, so there is a subsequence of the partial sums that converges.

Comment: d) Consider $(a_n) = (1, 1, -2, 2, 2, -4, 3, 3, -6, \cdots, n, n, -2n, \cdots)$. Then $n$ contains no convergent subsequence but $(s_n)$ does.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone reading this should be warned: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n$ does NOT converge to 0 or anything. The sequence of partial sums $(-1,0,-1,0,...)$ is certainly not convergent, furthermore, it does contain a convergent subsequence.

A proper and simpler example could be $a_n = 1$ which is bounded, but the sequence of partial sums $S_n = n$ contains no convergent subsequence.

b) The answer is yes. The reason is that a series converges iff its sequence of partial sums converges, then observe that every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same value.

On problem c and on part d, OP misinterprets the definition of subvergent. The definition states that the sequence of partial sums contains a convergent subsequence. This does not mean that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n_k}$ converges, it means that there is a sequence $S_{n_k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} a_i$ that converges.